# Where can I find the cost of the operations in Spark?

Tags: performance, apache-spark, rdd, processing-efficiency, memory-efficient

Let's say I have two RDDs with size M1 and M2, distributed equally into p partitions.

I'm interested in knowing that (theoretically / approximately) what is the cost of the operations filter, map, leftOuterJoin, ++, reduceByKey, etc.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, spark evaluates lazily, so it really depends on your full RDD operation chain because something might be optimized

Comment: On `Dataset`, you can use `explain` to give you a query plan.

Answer (score 5):

To measure the cost of execution it is important to understand how spark execution is performed.

In a nutshell, when you execute a set of transformations on your RDDs spark will create an execution plan (aka DAG), and group them together in the form of [stages](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/scheduler/Stage.html) which are executed once you trigger an action.

Operations like map/filter/flatMap are grouped together to form one stage since they do not incur a shuffle, and operations like join, reduceByKey will create more stages because they involve data to be moved across executors. Spark executes `action` as a sequence of `stages` (which gets executed sequentially or parallely if they are independent of each other). And, each `stage` gets executed as a number of parallel `tasks` where number of tasks running at a time depends upon the partitions of RDD and resources available.

Best way to measure the cost for your operations is to look at the SparkUI. Open the spark UI (by default it will be at localhost:4040 if you are running in local mode). You'll find several tabs on the top of the page, once you click on any of them you'll be directed to the page which will show you the corresponding metrics.

Here is what I do to measure the performance:

- Cost of a `Job` => Sum of costs of executing all its `stages`.
- Cost of a `Stage` => Mean of cost of executing each parallel `tasks` on the stage.
- Cost of a `Task` => By default, a task consumes one CPU core. Memory consumed is given in the UI which depends upon the size of your partition.

It is really difficult to derive metrics for each transformation within a `stage` since Spark combines these transformations and executes them together on a partition of RDD.